# set htpasswd to ask for credentials everytime

Tags: server, apache2, password, virtualhost

Is it possible to configure your `.htpasswd` file so that it asks for your credentials every time? Right now it only asks initially but I want it so that it asks every time the browser is reloaded.

my `.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName assignments
    DocumentRoot /var/www/assignments
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

 <Directory "/var/www/assignments">
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Hidden"
      AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
      Require valid-user
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "every time the browser is reloaded". It's not a setting on the webserver, but in the browser to cache the login. So the answer is no. What is the purpose?

Comment: by reload I mean every time you refresh the browser it would ask for your login info.. the purpose is just to see if its possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Actually, the server **will** ask for the credentials for each request. However, the login is cached on the Browser. There is nothing you can do server-side.

On Firefox, you can clear *Active Logins* from "History -> Clear Recent History" Menu (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>).

[See also](https://superuser.com/questions/181547/how-do-i-make-firefox-forget-http-basic-auth).